# What are the meaning of the special characters?

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

What are the meanings of the special characters shown when you hit the ¶ button on the home tab of word?

Comment: [Word’s nonprinting formatting marks](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/NonprintChars.htm)

Answer (score 1):

#### I like to see a table showing the special characters and their descriptions

> [image]

Source [Nonprinting Formatting Marks In Word](http://www.word-2010.com/nonprinting-formatting-marks-in-word-2010/)

See [Word’s nonprinting formatting marks](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/NonprintChars.htm) for more information.